# Django - Getting 'Required argument 'year' (pos 1) not found' error when trying to use datetime

Tags: python, django

My model has this in it:

```
start_date = models.DateField(default=datetime.date, blank=True)
stop_date = models.DateField(default=datetime.date, blank=True)
```

In my view I have:

```
start_date = datetime.date(int(request.POST.get('start_year')),
                           convert_month_to_int(request.POST.get('start_month')),
                           int(request.POST.get('start_day')))
end_date = datetime.date(int(request.POST.get('end_year')),
                         convert_month_to_int(request.POST.get('end_month')),
                         int(request.POST.get('end_day')))
```

before I save to the DB.

And the HTML is this:

```
                        <label class="col-md-4"> Start Date: </label>
                        <select class="selectpicker" data-width="auto" name="start_month" id="start_month" required>
                            {% for month in month_list %}
                                <option value="{{ month }}" {% if path_start and path_start.1 == month %} selected {% endif %}> {{ month }} </option>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </select>
                        /
                        <select class="selectpicker" data-width="auto" name="start_day" id="start_day" required>
                            {% for day in day_list %}
                                <option value="{{ day }}" {% if path_start and path_start.2 == day %} selected {% endif %}> {{ day }} </option>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </select>
                        /
                        <select class="selectpicker" data-width="auto" name="start_year" id="start_year" required>
                            {% for year in year_list %}
                                <option value="{{ year }}" {% if path_start and path_start.0 == year %} selected {% endif %}> {{ year }} </option>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <label class="col-md-4">End Date: </label>
                        <select class="selectpicker" data-width="auto" name="end_month" id="end_month">
                            {% for month in month_list %}
                                <option value="{{ month }}" {% if path_end and path_end.1 == month %} selected {% endif %}> {{ month }} </option>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </select>
                        /
                        <select class="selectpicker" data-width="auto" name="end_day" id="end_day">
                            {% for day in day_list %}
                                <option value="{{ day }}" {% if path_end and path_end.2 == day %} selected {% endif %}> {{ day }} </option>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </select>
                        /
                        <select class="selectpicker" data-width="auto" name="end_year" id="end_year">
                            {% for year in year_list %}
                                <option value="{{ year }}" {% if path_end and path_end.0 == year %} selected {% endif %}> {{ year }} </option>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </select>
```

I get the error 'Required argument 'year' (pos 1) not found' when I try to save. I can't figure out why this is happening. Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Could you show your view?

Comment: Check that you are receiving all data before you save your form including the values of start_year and end_year attributes.